# Is it possible to watch or log what manipulated a variable/an array during runtime in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, debugging

In my app, sometimes something empties an array, although nothing in the code itself interacts with the array at that time.
At the point where the array is emptied, a promise runs and if I comment out the promise, the array will not be emptied.
I cannot imagine that a promise, the code content of which has nothing to do with the array, empties it.
Hence my question whether one can watch or log during runtime what is manipulating the array.

Comment: Open browser DevTools (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`i`) -> Go to Sources (Chrome) or Debugger (Firefox) -> Open the file (`Ctrl`+`p`) -> Place breakpoints -> Step through the code. Or post a minimal reproducible example here instead of an opaque question.

Answer (score 1):

try to

1. List item use async pipe in angular, or using JSON pip to debug the ArrayList
2. for good performance try to read about: state management angular ngrx